# How to redirect a specific sub-domain to a main domain using in IIS using web.config?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config

Currently I have a sub-domain `https://blog.example.com` which I would like to redirect to `https://example.com/blog`. I'm using Craft CMS running on IIS 7 server.

I tried the code mentioned below but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect blog to new url" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/blog/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Update: Adding directory structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the condition you have specified. Your current pattern is **.*** which will result in a infinite loop. Change the pattern to check for the specific URL as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect blog to new url" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*blog\.example\.com.*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/blog/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried this and it works for me. Go to http://blog.kaushal.co.in

If you need to troubleshoot URL Rewrite rules, then enable **Failed Request tracing** for your site. See this for more details: [Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#configure-failed-request-tracing)

**UPDATE**

The rewrite rules need to be added to the 117072616095252 present at the **site's root "/"** and not in a web.config of one of the child folders.

Comment: For some reason its not working for me. How do I enable Failed Request tracing? I don't have access to the the server OS.

Comment: Clear the browser cache and then retry. The clients tend to cache the redirecting URL sometimes. See this for working with **Failed Request Tracing**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#configure-failed-request-tracing 

I am adding this to the answer

Comment: Is there any way to check if I'm editing the right file by triggering an error? Since there are multiple web.config files in the project directory.

Comment: You will have to put this section in the parent directory. It would help to know your directory structure

Comment: Currently I have added the code in web.config file which is placed in the Public directory

Comment: what do you mean by public directory? Can you add directory structure of your application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150201/discussion-between-rahul-dagli-and-kaushal-kumar-panday).